# How to update modal body and open on a link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to change some contents of bootstrap modal body on link click.
Here is the link code:

```
<a href="" id="login_link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Log In</a>
```

And Here is the JQuery code:

```
$('#login_link').click(function (element) {            
            $('#myModal').find('#signup_form').hide();
});
```

Here is the form inside Modal body:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="signup_form" name="signup_form" ></form>
```

On link click the modal is opening but modal body is not changing.
please help me.

**[UPDATES]**: Modal is **not getting the external js file** that manupulate the modal body.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js"></script>
```

the js codes works fine when it is the js codes directly embed along with modal.
So I need to know exactly where i have to put the external js file.Currently is it before  tag.

Comment: try to specify `$('#myModal').find('#signup_form').hide();`

Comment: put console.log inside click function and check if it is going in to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need click function if it is bootstrap modal?

Anyhow you have given "data-target and data-toggle" attribute so you can directly click a button without any click function.

refer https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp for better understanding of modal

You can try below code. This will hide form on popup of your modal

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                        $(this).('#signup_form').hide();
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $(document).on('click', '#login_link', function(){

       $('#myModal').find('#signup_form').hide();

    });
```